# AZURE DevOps the date a story moves into a column (swimlane)

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to display the date a story moves into a different column / swim lane on the story card so everyone looking at the board can see the length of time a story is in a column / swim lane.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: No. I would think it is a configuration of Azure DevOps

Comment: @Bob Lambie Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no field in the cards setting that can show the changed date for the column/swimlane.

[image]

The `Changed Date` field here is not only for column / swimlane changes, but also for other item changes.

In addition, the date displayed in the card can only be accurate to a certain day, not the specific time.

[image]

So, if you want to track the specific date of column/swimlane changes, you need to click into the story card and view it in **History**.

[image]